# Volume in menu bar can't be changed in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, audio, osx-lion

On my 21.5" iMac, the volume indicator doesn't work properly.

It started after I installed Sparrow about several days ago. It often disables itself for no reason at all. I've now uninstalled Sparrow and it's still doing the same thing.

Sometimes it disable itself for a few minutes and then enables itself again, sometimes it could be hours before it's enabled again. Sometimes I have to restart the computer a few times to get it to enable again.

[image]

I don't know what's the problem is here. I don't know why it does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens when your primary audio output device is *not* headphones or the built-in speakers of your Mac. For example, when you connect an external USB or Firewire sound card, or another virtual sound driver such as those from Adobe utilities (Premiere Pro, Media Encoder, …).

I don't think this is related to Sparrow in any way.

When it happens, hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> and click your volume icon in the menu bar.
If something other than "Internal speakers" is selected, then your audio controls won't work.

[image]

So, check what is listed in your case and remove the offending device/program.

---

If it's actually showing "Digital out", then that means your optical output is stuck. Your Mac thinks an optical cable is connected, when in fact it is not. This could be a hardware or software issue.

You can try the following software fix:

- Play some music
- Connect a pair of headphones
- Open *System Preferences » Sound*
- Disconnect the headphones

You could also [perform an SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) as [suggested here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3912113?start=0&tstart=0) – possibly with speakers or headphones plugged in.

Some others suggest this is a hardware problem. With a toothpick, [try fiddling around](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=6618965&postcount=9) in the headphone port, so that the latch releases again.

Comment: Yes it happened just now and on and off so many times, so freakin annoying. Here i took a screenshot ![screenshot][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EaoeW.png

How do stop it from being disable and enable for 100s of times everytime i use it? It's so annoying when i talk on skype and then its suddenly disable itself for 5mins or something then enable for 1 minute then disable again.

Comment: Have you connected any peripherals to your Mac? Any audio devices? Is the audio out port glowing red? If you haven't connected anything, try playing some music, then connect a pair of headphones. Open up "Sound" in System Preferences and pull out the headphones' cable again.

Comment: No there's no any sound devices connected to it. Here are the screenshots when i don't have any audio device connected and when i plug a pair of earphone in.https://picasaweb.google.com/104666350471310814512/May14201202?authuser=0&feat=directlink

Comment: https://picasaweb.google.com/104666350471310814512/May142012?authuser=0&feat=directlink

Comment: Okay, it seems that there's a hardware issue with that. If you search for "Mac stuck on Digital Out" you'll find lots of people with the same issue. Sometimes, the toothpick method (see my answer) works, sometimes the only solution is having the logic board replaced.

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll try to reset that smc and will see what happen. Thanks

Comment: Yes i now have done the reset smc and it works for about half an hour and it's now back to the old thing, enable and disable on and off all the time again. Do you think re-install os x lion would help? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I somehow didn't get your comments. As I said, I believe this is a hardware issue rather than a software problem. You might have bent a sensor inside the headphone port – it could be that you need to have the machine checked and repaired. @James1

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Yea I have just bought this computer 2nd hand from online store for about 2 weeks and all of a sudden, it became like this. I have asked the first owner and he said the computer has never been moved anywhere or open by any chance but yea i think it's just happen when i got it maybe. I'll give it a try to restore os x lion and if the problem still insist then i'll get it check. Thanks again.

Comment: I've had it get stuck (with internal speakers checked!) after disconnecting from a Thunderbolt display.

Answer (score 0):

•   BlueTooth connect, back to normal.

MenuBar volume grayed-out stuck on maxed-out while trying to adjust volume by tapping mute/softer/louder (F10/F11/F12) keys and earbud +/- controls.

•   MenuBar > Alt-volume > Sound Preferences... > Output volume: and Mute controls still work — although the grayed-out MenuBar volume indicators fail to update.

Quit/relaunch audio apps, earbuds in/out, no change.

Big screen transient pop-up volume indicator shows toggling mute-bar-sinister but below the big speaker icon is a small circle-bar-sinister icon apparently indicating audio failure.

Observed on MacBookAir7,2 MacOSX 10.11.6 VLC 3.0.2